# Multilingual site not changing language

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

My site has to be in english and spanish but the user should be able to select the language in their profile page.

I have this structure.
http://screencast.com/t/ArrNy8yDChM

On the search input I have this

```
         <input type="text" placeholder="@Resource.SearchBoxWatermark" class="form-control" name="top-search" id="top-search">
```

Then I have a profile edit view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile";
    Layout = "~/Areas/GlobalAdmin/Views/Shared/_LayoutGlobalAdmin.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
        <div class="row animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Profile Detail</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="ibox-content no-padding border-left-right">
                            <img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/profile_big.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content profile-content">
                            <h4><strong>Monica Smith</strong></h4>
                            <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Riviera State 32/106
                            </p>
                            <h5>
                                About me
                            </h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitat.
                            </p>
                            <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButton("Language", "English") English</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">@Html.RadioButton("Language", "Spanish") Spanish</label>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/GlobalAdmin/Views/Shared/_Toastr.cshtml");}
```

and the profile edit action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
                var user = (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User) await client.Users.GetByObjectId(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().Name).ExecuteAsync();
                var extPropLookupNameLanguage = $"extension_{SettingsHelper.ClientId.Replace("-", "")}_{"Language"}";
                user.SetExtendedProperty(extPropLookupNameLanguage, formCollection["Language"]);    
                await user.UpdateAsync();

                try
                {
                    string culture = string.Empty;
                    if (formCollection["Language"].ToString() == "English")
                    {
                        culture = "en-US";
                    }
                    else if (formCollection["Language"].ToString() == "Spanish")
                    {
                        culture = "es-CO";
                    }
                    var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureInfo.Name);
                    HttpCookie langCookie = new HttpCookie("culture", culture);
                    langCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(langCookie);
                    var toastrSuccess = "Perfil actualizado satisfactoriamente";
                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { toastrSuccess = toastrSuccess });

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var toastrError = ex.Message;
                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { toastrError = toastrError });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.toastrError = ex.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { toastrError = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

However when I select in the radio button, Spanish , the search input watermark is not changing to Spanish as here:

http://screencast.com/t/78YqMeMvx4qg

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a postback when you change the radio button? If there isn't, this is normal behavior. The view engine parses your resource string only once during page load. If you want to be able to change the language without having to refresh the page, you'll need to add some JavaScript.

Comment: yes check the return           return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { toastrSuccess = toastrSuccess });

Comment: I don't understand. Changing the radio button doesn't trigger a postback, clicking the submit does. Your resources will only show correctly if you refresh your page and handle the postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are setting the threads UICulture and Cultue only for a current thread (the one that executes your `Edit` action).At the end you are returning a redirect which basically returns a 302 status code to the client with the URL of you redirect action. Once client receives it, it issues additional request to this URL, however this request is handled by arbitrary thread taken from the thread pool. This threads UI culture is not set to Spanish and this is the reason that your resources don't work.
What you need to do is to add some code that is going parse your language cookie on each incoming request(in case that you are selecting a language for the whole application).

You can achieve it in multiple ways:

1)  Implement an IHttpModule and set the culture in the BeginRequest:

```
   void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["culture"] != null)
      {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["culture"];
        string lang = cookie.Value;
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
      }
   }
```

2) Override OnActionExecuting handler in your base controller:

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["culture"] != null)
      {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["culture"];
        string lang = cookie.Value;
        var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
      }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);           
  }
```